# Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical after changing domain

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content, canonical-url

I've recently changed the domain from `https://example.me` to `https://example.im`. However, `https://example.im` is not being displayed on Google. After inspecting it in the Search Console, this is what I got: "Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical".

How can I fix it?

Both `https://example.me` and `https://www.example.me` are now redirecting to `https://example.im`

[image]

Comment: I'd also use the url inspection tool on the old URL. I suspect it has not been crawled since the change. Do you have the old URL verified in the search console. I'm surprised the Google-selected canonical is set to N/A. You can also help things by adding canonical tags to your pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the steps you should have followed:

1. Change domain and apply `301 redirects` between the old and the new one.
2. Create Google Search Console property of the new domain (with http and https).
3. Apply `301 redirects` from http to https.
4. Make sure sitemap.xml contains only https URLs.
5. Make sure internal links points to https URLs.
6. There should be canonical tag pointing to https version of the URL.

Comment: Ok. It was already 301 redirects. I've added all non-https sites to Search Console now and requested to index. Also added canonical url to each page. Is there anything? How long should I wait for the changes to appear? I've submitted for 'Fetch and render'

Comment: Recently I've seen Google take 9 months to re-index all URLs of a large site when they were changed.   You certainly need to wait weeks if not months, even for a smaller site.  In the meantime users should be getting properly redirected even if Google sends them to the old URLs.

Comment: ok. Got it. I've to wait

Answer (score 2):

It can take several months for Google to process URL changes and index the new URLs.  It sounds like you have done the correct redirects.  For most URL changes you just need to wait.

In your case, Google does have a tool that can help when you are changing domain names.   You should use the [Search Console change of address tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en).   To use it you need to:

1. Redirect your old domain to your new domain. (You already did that.)
2. Verify your old and new domains in Google Search Console. (You may have already done that.)
3. Submit the change of address form letting Google know that the domain name for your site has changed.

Using this tool allows Google to process this type of move faster and with fewer ranking problems than other URL changes.