# URL is not on Google - what does it mean and how to fix?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, url

**ANOTHER POSSIBLE DUPLICATE:**

> [Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical after changing domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117316/duplicate-submitted-url-not-selected-as-canonical-after-changing-domain)

I'm new to optimizing pages for ranking in search engines and I've recently got in Google Search Console. 
So whenever I try the `URL Inspection` tool with the home page of my site I get this message:

> URL is not on Google
>
> This page is not in the index, but not because of
>   an error. See the details below to learn why it wasn't indexed. Learn
>   more

Here's a more detailed view:
[image]

I'm feeling really frustrated because I don't really know what does this mean and there's no real actionable information on how to fix this.

However, when I try the `Test Live URL` feature I get the following:

[image]

This looks kind of ambigious information to me and I don't know if I should be worried?

I've tried to stick to the most fundamental practices for SEO so that everything on the page is moderately OK and does not have critical issues such as `noindex` etc.